# Tiff median filter exports as single frame OpenCV Python

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, tiff

I'm trying to have a program run over a sequence of 60 frames (in a tiff file) and apply a noise reduction filter (Median) in order to clean the frames up a bit before analysis. However, my program (which takes it frame by frame) will output a single-frame tiff; why is that? How could I take care of that?

```
from PIL import Image
import cv2
import numpy as np

im = Image.open('example_recording.tif').convert('L')
im.save('greyscale_example.tif') #converts to greyscale

width,height = im.size
image_lookup = 0

class ImageSequence:
    def __init__(self, im):
        self.im = im
    def __getitem__(self, ix):
        try:
            if ix:
                self.im.seek(ix)
            return self.im
        except EOFError:
        raise IndexError # if end of sequence

for frame in ImageSequence(im):
        imarray = np.array(frame)
        Blur = cv2.medianBlur(imarray,5)
        frame = Image.fromarray(Blur)

im.save('corrected.tif')
```

Comment: Do you have a sample file? Do you mean you want a single image which is the median of all the images in a single file?

Comment: No, I am trying to apply median filter to every frame, in order to filter out noise from a short movie. I do have a sample file, however to upload it anywhere would require format conversion to gif anyway; damn thing is almost 600 MB (but can do, if it helps). End result should be a single file tiff sequence of 60 frames, with median filter applied on every single one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are not re-composing your final stack correctly (not shown above?), and saving a single frame (the last frame)?

An alternative is to forgo OpenCV and use scipy:

```
import numpy
import scipy
from scipy import ndimage

a = numpy.random.randint(0,255,(100,100,60))
a.shape
#(100L, 100L, 60L)

b = scipy.ndimage.filters.generic_filter(a, numpy.median, 5)
b.shape
#(100L, 100L, 60L)
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm not entirely sure how I would go about re-composing the final stack back, was hoping that frame=image.fromarray would convert frame by frame, leaving the structure of the sequence untouched.

As far as scipy goes, I have very little experience with it, so I may have to do some reading before being able to apply the solution you proposed and evaluate whether it solves the problem; thanks in the meantime!

Comment: I don't see where `frame` is put back into `im`. I don't see it used after it is assigned? The second time you use `frame`, it is setting it as though it were a new variable, overwriting the name, but not writing back to your ImageSequence instance.

Comment: Yes, I believe that now I understand where I made a mistake. How would I go about putting it back inside?